# How to get variables and save them in a list of Object from an array in a firebase remote config array value using gson?

Tags: java, android, json, gson, firebase-remote-config

so, I have to use firebase remote config in a project for some clients, and I am using a key to store a value and the value is not like a String, etc... but rather an array. let's say that the value looks like this:

```
 
 [
      {
        "owner": "jon",
        "year": 2019
      },
      {
        "owner": "Alex",
        "versionCode": 2032
      },
      ...
 ]
```

how am I supposed to  get the owner and year and save them in a list of Laptops  with gson?

Laptops.java look like this btw:

```
public class Laptop() {
    private String owner;
    private int year;

    // constructor
    ...
    // getters and setters
    ...
}
```

The answer from this post: [Can I declare an array to Firebase Remote config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42201937/can-i-declare-an-array-to-firebase-remote-config) kinda helped but the answer is in kotlin, and I think the syntax is not exactly the same in java
Thanks in advance!

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314813/json-gson-fromjson-java-objects replace "this.json" with your json string

Comment: @Elvis Hi, sorry for the late reply; it's just that I can't figure out what "this" is in that case? in the comments he says that "it's input json string" ? I don't really know what that means and I think the syntax for that may have changed since 2011?